# Get location about didUpdateLocations and didUpdateToLocation never call on ios 5.1 and ios6

Tags: ios, google-maps, location

I have a question about location.

I need to get location of latitude and longitude at iOS 5.1 and iOS 6 upper.

But I write NSLog in didUpdateLocations and didUpdateToLocation function .

I had not saw the log show in console.

I am use simulate set location . I am test latitude value is 25.317973, longtitude value is 121.538161 (D1).

Then I am test value is ( 25.917973, 121.538161 ) (D2).

D1 and D2 distance is more than 10 meter;

But I never saw the log show in console.

I attach my code below:

my .h file

```
#mport <GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
#import <Corelocation/CLLocationManagerDelegate.h> 

@interface LocationMapViewController : AbstractViewController<     CLLocationManagerDelegate, GMSMapViewDelegate >
@property (strong, nonatomic) CLLocationManager *locationManager;
@end
```

my .m file

```
   - (void)viewDidLoad
       {
           [super viewDidLoad];

 if( _locationManager == nil )
    {
        _locationManager =  [CLLocationManager new];
        _locationManager.delegate = self;

        _locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
        _locationManager.distanceFilter = 10.0f;
        [_locationManager startUpdatingHeading];

    }

-(void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray     *)locations
{
    NSLog(@"==latitude %f, longitude %f", [[locations objectAtIndex:([locations     count]-1)] coordinate].latitude , [[locations objectAtIndex:([locations count]-1)]     coordinate].longitude);
}

-(void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation     *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
     NSLog(@"====latitude %f, longitude %f", newLocation.coordinate.latitude,     newLocation.coordinate.longitude);
}
```

Have anyone know what's wrong with my code?

thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have to import the `CLLocationManagerDelegate` in your .h and AFAIK I think `CoreLocation` is not using Google Maps as well, so unless you are using the Google Maps API or something there should be no need to import the GoogleMaps as well.

Try using this instead in your method:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    if( _locationManager == nil )
    {
       _locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
       _locationManager.delegate = self;
       _locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;

       [_locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    }
}
```

edit:

I realised that you are trying to get the difference in the distance. So maybe just change your

```
_locationManager = [CLLocationManager new];
```

to

```
_locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
```

and that should solve the problem.

Following your comment, I have checked a little more, and realised that you are using the `startUpdatingHeading` method call, therefore you should be using the `didUpdateHeading` delegate methods. This is from the Apple `CLLocationManager` reference:

> Heading events are delivered to the locationManager:didUpdateHeading: method of your     delegate. If there is an error, the location manager calls the locationManager:didFailWithError: method of your delegate instead.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: I had tried you method. But I still not get any log in my console. :(
I had tried set difference in the distance.
I don't know what problem cause . 
I had use google maps api , so I import this header file.
thank you

Comment: I am understand where is my wrong.
Because I have not changed startUpdatingHeading to startUpdatingLocation.
Thank you very much, faterpig.